# why i get in the console this class error

Tags: python-3.x, python-sockets

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__client_socket = socket.create_connection((HOST, PORT))
        self.__t = threading.Thread(target=self.display_msg)
        self.__t.daemon = True
        self.__t.start()

    def display_msg(self):
        while True:
            r, w, x = select.select([self.__client_socket], [], [], 0.00001)
            if self.__client_socket in r:
                data = self.__client_socket.recv(1024).decode()
```

Does anyone has any idea why I get this error " 'User' object has no attribute '_User__client_socket' "

Comment: How are you trying to access the attribute? from inside or outside the class?

Comment: inside beacuse the the thread call the function when an object creates.

Comment: can you show the full stack trace of the error to show exaclty which line in your code this happens on